# How to copy changing values down a column

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet and I need to copy the URLs from column B into column A, but I need the URLs to repeat all the way down column A even when there is a "-" in column B.

So in the screenshot below, I need A1 to A5 to be the URL in B1 and then A6 to A35 needs to be the URL in B6 etc.

How can I make a formula to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `A1`:

```
=$B1
```

In cell `A2` and below:

```
=IF($B2="-",$A1,$B2)
```